# ssdeep fuzzy hashes and frida server binaries

Tags: frida

I am doing some testing on fuzzy hashing and was using frida server binaries as examples. I was assuming that newer versions of frida server will build on top of existing code and so there should be a high percentage of similarity between each release. However, when I did a ssdeep comparison between minor versions such as 12.11.14 and 12.11.13, I found that the similarity is 0 (no similarity).

I was wondering if someone else has tried this before? Has this got to do with how the frida server code is compiled?

Example of fuzzy hashing frida_server_12.11.14_ios_arm64 and frida_server_12.11.13_ios_arm64

```
filename frida-server-12.11.14-ios-arm64 393216:8ljDmG+xQiYfCR1t1rK8JuMwlG/WjeZFO5r+vxLEf8FC/ie:cvY5IMwlUWjeZFLxC
filename2 frida-server-12.11.13-ios-arm64 393216:hWCJZ51p1Y1flpCv5iu1rK42BQAtcqg9EywtUQO82xsT89C/7mekv:hLP6+kBQAtvg9Eywj2Eu
```

The comparison function in ssdeep returned 0, which means the signatures did not match.

However, when I compared the various architectures (arm, arm64 and arm64e) within the same version (12.11.14), there are some similarities.

```
filename frida-server-12.11.14-ios-arm64 393216:8ljDmG+xQiYfCR1t1rK8JuMwlG/WjeZFO5r+vxLEf8FC/ie:cvY5IMwlUWjeZFLxC
filename2 frida-server-12.11.14-ios-arm 196608:BpN3Tm15GpZHGG+xQiYMxi/s60k01dX1rKCVasZDpeCVR:XNjDmG+xQiYfCR1t1rK+e
fuzzy hashes comparison 57
```

```
filename frida-server-12.11.14-ios-arm64 393216:8ljDmG+xQiYfCR1t1rK8JuMwlG/WjeZFO5r+vxLEf8FC/ie:cvY5IMwlUWjeZFLxC
filename2 frida-server-12.11.14-ios-arm64e 786432:BBMMwlUWjeZFLxC99NMeQEaB9GFLM6j7D:VdyD
fuzzy hashes comparison 49
```

Comment: I am not sure how good ssdeep is suited for such comparisons. Your question is close to the topic "reproducible builds with Xcode" which has been discussed a lot in the last years. See for example https://twitter.com/steipete/status/1267926133988786176